# C# Label value changes but text on UI doesn't

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

I've a Winforms program in which I retrieve some data from database asynchronously, and display it on the UI. This is the function I'm using to display `User & Scan` iinformation on labels:

```
private async Task PopulateLastScanAsync()
        {
            var scan = await Access.GetLastScanAsync(); // retrieve User/Scan data from database
            if (scan.Item4) // Ignore this stuff
            {
                var result = await Access.GetUserAsync(scan.Item1.UserCode);
                if (result.Item2)
                {
                    // Display logic is here
                    User usr = result.Item1; // Display on UI
                    LastScannedName.Text = $"{usr.FirstName} {usr.LastName}";
                    LastScannedUserId.Text = $"{usr.UserCode}";
                    LastScanTime.Text = scan.Item1.ScanTime.ToString("g");
                    LastScanImage.Image = Manager.ConvertBytesToImage(usr.Picture);
                    // Read following comments after going thru the problem
                    // If here, I debug, like Console.WriteLine(LastScannedName.Text), it displays correct results on console, but incorrect text on UI. [During Timer_Tick event]
                }
            }
        }
```

I've called this method in `Form_Load` Event, this event just displays the last scanned information on UI, and it works perfect:

```
private async void UC_Dashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopulateLastScanAsync();
            timerRefresher.Start();
        }
```

I've a timer `timerRefresher`, which ticks after every few seconds, it's purpose is to refresh the data displayed on UI. The code in its tick event is:

```
private async void timerRefresher_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopulateLastScanAsync();
        }
```

**The Problem** is: Data is correctly displayed on UI when form loads, but the ticks event isn't refreshing the updated values on the labels.

I know this problem is coming from `async` stuff, but don't know how to get rid of it.
What I've tried:

```
- Label.Update();
- Label.Refresh();
- Label.Invoke();
- Label.Invalidate();
// And some other stuff answered in other similar questions
```

and other methods that come with `Label` control.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the timer declaration?

Comment: @Vernou timer is declared on Designer, I just have dragged it from toolbox.

Comment: Ok, I think the timer don't execute the tick on UI thread. Try modify properties to execute on the UI thread, else see @AnantDabhi's anwer.

Comment: Is here any way, we can know whether a piece of code is being executed on a UI thread on any other one?

Comment: Try replacing the code inside the `timerRefresher_Tick` handler with this: `await Task.Delay(100); LastScannedName.Text += "*";`. Do you see the text in the label updated?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias on the UI, text doesn't updates, but if debug on console using `Console.WriteLine(LastScannedName.Text)`, console shows the updated value. But UI doesn't. And even not an exception is thrown.

Comment: If you remove the `await Task.Delay(100);` and leave only the `LastScannedName.Text += "*";` inside the handler, is the label updated then? Please try it without the debugger attached. Start the program from the Visual Studio with Ctrl+F5.

Comment: It's the same thing again. Tried after removing console debugger. The `LastScannedName.Text` gives different value compared to displayed on UI. 
If you have a minute, can you connect to my pc to interact with the code?

Comment: I am not interested if the value is the same or different. I am interested if the label is updated on every `Tick`, or remains frozen to its initial value forever. About connecting to your PC, I can't do it, sorry.

Comment: Label remains frozen on the initial value. I had made `timerRefresher` access public and was starting the `timerRefresher` from a different form. I just tried to start from the same form and it works now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where are you showing these Controls (`LastScannedName` & Co.)?  -- Add a check in `PopulateLastScanAsync()`: `bool hasHandle = LastScannedName.IsHandleCreated;`. If `hasHandle` is `false`, then `var handle = LastScannedName.Handle` etc. See whether this makes the Controls update. Remove all those `.Refresh()`, `.Update()` etc. Also, print to the Console `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`, see what that is. Unless there's something you're saying, async/await resumes in the U Thread.

Comment: "and was starting the timerRefresher from a different form."  Your problem is most likely a reference issue, where you are creating an instance of the first form and thinking that will allow you to change the existing form that is already on your screen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call method from method in `Form_Load` Event with `await` `PopulateLastScanAsync()` method will execute in MainThread so it will update UI.

and when you calling same method via another thread(Not UI/Dispatcher thread) it will throw exception.

if you put Try catch block in `PopulateLastScanAsync()` method you can get exception.

you can call Dispatcher thread to perform UI related changes.

Updated code :

```
         private async Task PopulateLastScanAsync()
    {
        var scan = await Access.GetLastScanAsync(); // retrieve User/Scan data from database
        if (scan.Item4) // Ignore this stuff
        {
            var result = await Access.GetUserAsync(scan.Item1.UserCode);
            if (result.Item2)
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {

                    // Display logic is here
                    User usr = result.Item1; // Display on UI
                    LastScannedName.Text = $"{usr.FirstName} {usr.LastName}";
                    LastScannedUserId.Text = $"{usr.UserCode}";
                    LastScanTime.Text = scan.Item1.ScanTime.ToString("g");
                    LastScanImage.Image = Manager.ConvertBytesToImage(usr.Picture);
                    // Read following comments after going thru the problem
                    // If here, I debug, like Console.WriteLine(LastScannedName.Text), it displays correct results on console, but incorrect text on UI. [During Timer_Tick event]

                });
        }
    }
}
```

- Its always good idea to check `InvokeRequired` before updating any control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I've tried the mentioned things. 
1. I've enclosed the method in try-catch block, not getting any exception.
2. I tried to use `this.Invoke` and got an exception, `control can't be invoked/begin unless its handle is created`
3. I enclosed that code in `InvokeRequired` check, which always returns false, even if label needs an UI update.

Comment: have you checked                     LastScannedName.Text = $"{usr.FirstName} {usr.LastName}";
is updated via Debug ?

Comment: I've added a line of code within the `PopulateLastScanAsync()`: `Console.WriteLine(LastScannedName.Text)`. When called from `Timer_Tick`, the value on console is different from the one on UI.

Comment: Did you actually solve your problem?  Your last comment makes it seem like you didn't...

Answer (score 1):

You should separate your your data gathering from your UI management.

```cs
private async Task PopulateLastScanAsync()
{
    var usr = await GetLastScanDataAsync(); // retrieve User/Scan data
    if (usr != null) // Ignore this stuff
    {
        LastScannedName.Text = $"{usr.FirstName} {usr.LastName}";
        LastScannedUserId.Text = $"{usr.UserCode}";
        LastScanTime.Text = scan.Item1.ScanTime.ToString("g");
        LastScanImage.Image = Manager.ConvertBytesToImage(usr.Picture);
    }
}

private async Task<LastScan> GetLastScanDataAsync()
{
    var scan = await Access.GetLastScanAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // retrieve User/Scan data from database
    if (scan.Item4) // Ignore this stuff
    {
        var result = await Access.GetUserAsync(scan.Item1.UserCode).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.Item2)
        {
            return result.Item1;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

For more information regarding `ConfigureAwait(false)`, read [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

You don't show what time of timer you're using, but if you were using a [Windows Forms Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer), I wouldn't expect any issues because:

> **Note**
>
> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the **Timer** class in the **System.Timers** namespace.